# Unable to send message cards to teams webhook

Tags: microsoft-teams, webhooks

I have successfully created a webhook for my teams channel. I am following this guide here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/send-via-connectors. I can send simple message to teams like    `{"text":"testing","title":"Alert from  postman","textFormat":"markdown"}` [image]

I am unable to send MessageCards [image: See full payload in the link above]

[image]

error as below
[image]

It doesn't like anything "@" in the json , if i remove them i get bad request, What am doing wrong?

Comment: We tried this at our end and the card got sent successfully using Postman. Based on the error "read ECONNRESET", the below could be the possible issues. SSL certification or VPN Issue.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT: I have tried curl and same issue, Noticed that it worked for one of  my colleague and same issue as mine on another colleague. I didn't have this issue with adaptive cards, so looking to use it instead. Sounds like message cards are legacy ones. The SSL certification in the postman preference is turned off.